# Initial Value Problem, $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\sec^2(t)}{y+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having difficulty solving the initial value problem $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\operatorname{sec}^2(t)}{y+1}$$ where $t\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $y(0)=-2$. I started by moving $y$ across, however, after integrating and solving I ended up with the wrong answer.

I also have to state the domain of the solution.

Comment: What wrong answer did you obtain? Could you show us all the steps you used to obtain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{\sec^2(t)}{y+1}$

So $(y+1)\,dy = \sec^2(t)\,dt$.

This gives $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}y^2+y=\tan(t)+C$.

Then $\displaystyle y^2+2y+1=2\tan(t)+C$.

Thus $\displaystyle \left(y+1\right)^2=2\tan(t)+C$.

So $\boxed{\displaystyle y = \pm\sqrt{2\tan(t)+C}-1}$.

This would only be valid for a portion of a single period of $\tan$ where $2\tan(t)+C \ge 0. $

UPDATE: if $y(0)=-2$, then $-2 = -\sqrt{0+C}-1$, so $C=1$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \boxed{y=-\sqrt{2\tan(t)+1}-1}$.

Therefore, the domain is $\displaystyle \boxed{t \in \left(\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right),\frac{π}{2}\right)}$

This is because we must have the function defined on the entire interval, and $\sqrt{2\tan(t)+1} $ is defined when $\displaystyle \tan(t)>-\frac{1}{2}$. Since $\tan$ is strictly increasing on the interval, we only need to check its zero.

Comment: $y(0)=-2$, not 2

Comment: oh crap sorry let me fix...

Comment: @SakethMalyala would you be able to explain what did you do between $\frac{1}{2}y^2+y=\tan(t)+C$ and $y^2+2y+1=2\tan(t)+C$

Comment: sure! i multiplied by 2. then i take plus or minus. i have to decide to take the positive root or the negative root. if y(0)=-2, then i must take the negative root. then i solve for C

Comment: @randb
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+y=\tan{t}+C$$
$$y^2+2y=2\tan{t}+2C$$
$$y^2+2y+1=2\tan{t}+2C+1$$
Note that since $C$ is an arbitrary constant, one may let $k=2C+1$

Comment: and then K will be another arbitrary constant

Comment: @SakethMalyala thanks for explaining but where did the +1 come from in $y^2+2y+1=2\tan(t)+C$

Comment: oh i randomly added it to both sides to complete the square.

Comment: you can do that, because then C absorbs the +1 and becomes (C+1) which is an arbitrary constant

Answer (score 4):

If you separate variables, you end up with
$$
\frac{(y+1)^2}{2} = \int \operatorname{sec}^2 t \, dt.
$$
Now you compute the right-hand side, apply the IV condition and solve for $y$. Is this different than your solution?

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I separated the y and 1 terms, I now see where I went wrong

Comment: I like this answer, since using $\int (y+1)~dy=\frac{(y+1)^2}{2}+C$ instead of $\int (y+1)~dy=\frac{y^2}{2}+y+C$ (The constants of integration differ) is a lot more convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using the initial condition, and assuming $y+1\ne0$,

$$\int_{-2}^y(y+1)dy=\int_0^t\sec^2t\,dt$$ yields

$$\frac{(y+1)^2-1}2=\tan t,$$

or

$$y=-\sqrt{2\tan t+1}-1$$ (the positive square root does not work).

This is only valid when $2\tan t+1>0$, i.e. $$t>-\arctan\frac12.$$